# Not able to connect to MySQL server using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, connection, pdo, host

I have a PHP script which I use to connect to a MySQL database. Connection through mysql_connect works perfectly, but when trying with PDO I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname' (3)
```

the code I use to connect is below:

```
    <?php  
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $hostname_localhost ="hostname";  
    $database_localhost ="dbname";  
    $username_localhost ="user";  
    $password_localhost ="pass";  
    $user = $_GET['user'];  
    $pass = $_GET['pass'];

    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_localhost;dbname=$database_localhost",$username_localhost,$password_localhost);
        echo 'Connected to DB';
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT check_user_company(:user,:pass)");
        $stmt = $dbh->bindParam(':user',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR, 16);
        $stmt = $dbh->bindParam(':pass',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo $row['company_id'].'<br />';
        }

        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } 
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error's obvious enough... the specified hostname cannot be resolved to an IP address.

Comment: Where it says "hostname" you are supposed to fill in *your* mySQL server's host name or IP address.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using IP adresses (and that IP address is also in the error) but I changed the values on purpose for security reasons

Comment: Your IP address is incorrect, or there is no mySql server running there that you can access.

Comment: now that explains why I AM able to connect with regular mysql_connect statement using exactly the same var's..

Comment: I solved the problem, on the declaration of :

    $hostname_localhost

I also put the port number in the statement, after adding: `port=$port_localhost` it worked

Comment: @user1337210 Could you please post your working code? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

Got the same problem. Mine solution was another database port. I wrote localhost:1234 and got this error.

Fixed with:

```
mysql:host=$hostname_localhost;port=1234;dbname=$database_localhost",$username_localhost,$password_localhost);
        echo 'Connected to DB';
```

Answer (score 3):

It does seem pretty straightforward, here is what I use to build my PDO connectors(noticed your dbname and host are done differently than mine, dunno if that's relevant, but worth a check):

***PDO Creation function***

```
require_once('config.inc.php');

function buildDBConnector(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.C_BASE.';host='.C_HOST;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, C_USER, C_PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

***config.inc.php***

```
define('C_HOST','localhost');// MySQL host name (usually:localhost)
define('C_USER','sweetUsername');// MySQL username
define('C_PASS','sweetPassword');// MySQL password
define('C_BASE','superGreatDatabase');// MySQL database
```

And while it makes no sense, when I tried to declare `$dsn` inline including variables during the `newPDO` call, I kept getting failures too.  I broke it apart and used the $dsn variable to do so.  And haven't had an issue since.

Wondering if you're in shared hosting by chance?

***NOTE:***
If you don't have a dedicated IP, and instead are going through a NAT, your IP won't properly translate to your actual server.

That help at all?

***UPDATE:***
Just thought of another thing.  Are you trying to connect to a mysql database that is on a different IP than you are running your scripts from?  If so, you will likely need to enable remoteSQL access for the ip you are calling the database from.  Fairly easy to do, but CRITICAL if you are not accessing localhost.

Comment: How does one enable remoteSQL access?

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to specify the database host dns details or IP address. Adding that will solve the problem