# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have this **error** when i try to access to some web pages of my project:`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)`

**alwaysdata** is the ***phpmyadmin website*** I use for my database.

I noticed that it's when I try to access in some pages in relation with the database (create user for example... etc) and there's no problems with other pages like 'contact'.

I'm on mac OSX and I use MAMP server, always data, laravel and netbeans IDE. all configurations required to make the connection between my project and the database is correct.

Here it is:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)`

> open:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lesenfantsdurhone/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php

```
 */
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
    $username = array_get($config, 'username');

    $password = array_get($config, 'password');

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

If someone have an idea...

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573583/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-server-using-pdo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The port has it's [own parameter in the DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php):

```
'mysql:host=mysql1.alwaysdata.com;port=3306;dbname=xxx'
```

Alternatively just omit the port, 3306 is the default port.

Comment: thank you, in fact I just remove 3306 in 
`'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
 'host'      => 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306',
),.

But, I ask me why it works now, 3306 is the default port.

Comment: Had the same problem w/my PDO connection.  And the stupid part is it worked locally on my Windows machine, but it bombed on my Ubuntu dev server.  Removing the port from the string solved it since it was just using the default mysql port anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while using Laravel with MAMP and Sequal Pro.

Inside the `.env` file, I set the

```
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = "3306"
```

and this worked.

Before, I had

```
DB_HOST = "localhost:8889"
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error because of the failing DNS service due to the time on my Virtualbox being off - it does that after you put your host machine to sleep for example.

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had double definition of DB_HOST variable in  '.env' file
First one is correct:`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

And last one was
`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:3306`
with unwanted 3306

That was the cause.