# Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After a php verison change i have the following error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 
'clouddb.myhost.gr:3306' (2) in 
/var/www/vhosts/mywebside.gr/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on 
line 7Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in 
/var/www/vhosts/mywebside.gr/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on 
line 10Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in 
/var/www/vhosts/mywebside.gr/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on 
line 10 .
```

And i cant understand what is the problem

Comment: Take the `:3306` out of your host, port goes in a separate field. But it's not needed if you're using the default port (3306).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2005\] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955446/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-mysql1-alwaysdata-com3306-2)

Comment: i was take out the port from my config file and worked finaly! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be passing the clouddb.myhost.gr:3306 all together, on the mysqlcli, the port have its own parameter:

```
mysql:host=clouddb.myhost.gr;port=3306;
```

Related question:

[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955446/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-mysql1-alwaysdata-com3306-2)