# PDO cannot connect to MySQL but CLI can

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Made a test script:

```
<?php
$a = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=mydbhost:3306', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
var_dump($a);
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mydbhost:3306' (107)' in /users/pvarney/test_pdo.php:3 Stack trace:
#0 /users/pvarney/test_pdo.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=my...', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
#1 {main}   thrown in /users/pvarney/test_pdo.php on line 3
```

Then via CLI:

```
[pvarney@ci-server ~]$ mysql mydbname -h mydbhost -u myusername -p --port=3306
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 828511

... snip mysql welcome text ...

mysql>
```

I've changed the connection string to mask connection information, but I did copy-paste it into the CLI to make sure I didn't have any typos.

Comment: `host=mydbhost;port=3306`

Comment: Can you try this? ````new PDO('mysql:host=mydbhost;port=3306;dbname=mydbname', 'myusername', 'mypassword');````

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Oddly enough my connection string worked in 5.4 but not 5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=mydbhost:3306', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
```

to

```
new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname; host=mydbhost; port=3306;', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the PHP docs for [PDO_MYSQL_DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). The port should be passed as a separate parameter:

```
mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=mydbhost;port=3306
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post :
[Not able to connect to MySQL server using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573583/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-server-using-pdo)

Try changing the port setting

Answer (score 2):

```
 $a = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=mydbhost;port=3306', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
                                                 /*note ^^*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open file something like /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
2. Find the entry   pdo_mysql.default_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
3. Change that to what you want.
   That's all.