# What does the number in brackets at the end of SQLSTATE errors mean?

Tags: mysql, exception

I have this error when trying to connect to my cloud-hosted database via my website :

`Error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'database-host-name:port' (-2)`

While searching to try to figure out why I can't connect to the MySQL server, I noticed everyone encountering a similar error had a different number in brackets at the end of their error, stuff like (0) or (1), but no negative number like me, which lead me to wonder what the number meant.

Tried looking at the documentation but couldn't find the answer to this.

This is the code generating the error :

```php
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=database-host-name:port;dbname=database-name;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Which is called by :

```php
require_once('bdd.php');
```

**Just to be clear, I am not asking for help concerning fixing the error, I'm just curious to know what the number in brackets represents.**

Thanks in advance !

---

After changing the dsn to this (as I was told it should be done):

`'mysql:host=database-host-name;port=port;dbname=database-name;charset=utf8'`

The error is now :

`Error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database-host-name' (115)`

My question still stands.

Once again, I am not asking for help to fix the error, I just want to know what the '(-2)' meant in the first error, and what '(115)' represents in this new error.

---

Using this link as an example : [Not able to connect to MySQL server using PDO [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573583/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-server-using-pdo)

That user's error was :

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname' (3)`

Why does his error ends with a '(3)' and mine with a '(-2)'?

Comment: is database-host-name:port a real hostname or you just edited it out?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I edited it out to avoid revealing potentially sensitive information, same as the port, username and password

Comment: why you're writing it this way, host:port while in the php manual it says that port is written differently?

Comment: I don't think my question should have been flagged as a duplicate, since the 'duplicate' question asks for help concerning the error, whilst my question concerns what the error contains, not how to fix it. They are two firmly different questions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I edited, but my question still stands.