# MySQL 5.7 - Error 2005. What does the number in brackets mean?

Tags: mysql

Trying to debug an issue right now and having a hard time figuring out exactly what the error I'm getting from MySQL is.

The error is

`Unknown MySQL server host 'db_host_name' (-2)`

From the MySQL docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/5.6/en/client-error-reference.html)

```
Error number: 2005; Symbol: CR_UNKNOWN_HOST;

Message: Unknown MySQL server host '%s' (%d)
```

This is not overly clear from the documentation what this error actually means, but based on my googling around it appears to be a DNS name resolution error, which is what I figured.

What I'm unclear on, is why there appears to be different numbers at the end. Online I've seen the name error with (0), (1), and (-2) like mine. The details of what this number means may be revealing to my underlying issue, but I just cannot find what this means anywhere, and the mysql documentation barely recognizes the existence of this number.

I found this question: [What does the number in brackets at the end of SQLSTATE errors mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291216/what-does-the-number-in-brackets-at-the-end-of-sqlstate-errors-mean) but it was never answered.

Comment: I think you may be concentrating on the wrong part of the error message. The first part really say all you need to know

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I understand that. I've been up all night exhausting through an intermittent production issue so I'm looking as deep as possible at all avenues. Any hint to the issue like finding more detailed error codes can help with root causing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the host 'db_host_name' cannot be found. If you're running MySQL locally you should probably change to host to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

About the underlying error, looking at the source code of MySQL 5.7, in this case it's the error code returned from `getaddrinfo()` reported here:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/e081d4dc0f6f9ffc0e430a2417011edafaff7ca2/sql-common/client.c#L4325

Comment: My issue is not consistent. This is an issue running in production and it happens intermittently. There can be multiple root causes for a hostname that cannot be found which I am trying to track down. 

Thank you for tracking down where the number comes from, I'm now currently trying to track down what -2 means from getaddrinfo.

Comment: I see. The host name actually used is `db_host_name`? Otherwise it might be a problem with the propagation of environment variables. To track further  What OS is the MySQL instance running on? `getaddrinfo()` is defined in `netdb.h` if it is not running on Windows.

Comment: No, the db_host_name in this case is an aws rds aurora writer cluster endpoint. Amazingly we've tracked the DNS issues down to (what appears to be so far, we're opening tickets) an AWS bug when scaling down read replicas in aurora, the cluster writer endpoint NXDOMAINs for a period of about a minute. I'll accept your answer, but it would be improved by including the actual return values from getaddrinfo

Comment: Update on this in case you happen to be interested: It was in fact an AWS bug, and we've got acknowledgement from them on that and are awaiting their fix